# How to get key values from "array string" in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have an array in Laravel controller like:

```
$succeeded[] = array('name' => $name,
                    'file' => $file
                        );
...
return $succeeded;
```

I use an ajax call for getting `$succeeded`, and I'll have a return string in js function composed of:

```
"[{"name":"sor.jpg","file":"399393.jpg"}]"
```

My question is how can I get "name" and "file" values from the string above?

Note: I didn't use any JSON object in controller, but returned just the array. However I wonder it is advantageous to use JSON object.

Comment: I presume that's supposed to be json? because if so, it's not valid json. And even if it was legitimate json, You don't access the json string directly. You **decode** the string to a native structure, and then you access the data like you would in any other data structure.

Comment: The returned value isn't a JSON object. I don't know whether it is advantageus to use JSON object in controller, though.

Comment: It is not a JSON object.

Comment: Well, that is a JSON encoded *string*.  And, if you are returning that in an AJAX request, then you'll need to parse the JSON string into a javascript *object*.

Comment: Are the outmost wrapping quotes included in the string? If that's the case, you've to remove them before parsing.

Comment: @Teemu Yes, string is that.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to parse the response text into a JSON array using the native `JSON.parse`, and then you can extract the values from the object in the parsed array using dot notation.

```
var respText = "[{\"name\":\"sor.jpg\",\"file\":\"399393.jpg\"}]";
var arr = JSON.parse(respText)[0];  // Careful - this will throw on invalid JSON
var name = arr.name;  // "sor.jpg"
var file = arr.file;  // "399393.jpg"
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not useful.  I understand what you are doing and why, but the code is a bit "compact", and would be unclear to a less experienced javacript coder.  So - explain what you are doing at each step.  You can ALSO point out a couple of alternatives - for example `var arr = JSON.parse(respText); var obj = arr.shift(); var name = obj['name'];`....

Comment: `dot` *or bracket* notation....

Comment: There are valid scenarios where you are *required* to use bracket notation, but the choice between dot notation and bracket notation for regular (alphabetic) strings is nothing more than a matter of style preference.

Comment: My point is this: You can point out the options.  Bracket notation is very useful in many situations.